# cakePHP, encoding problem when using find+list, no problem when using find+all

Tags: list, cakephp, encoding, find

Well, I've configured the `database.php` file, added the `'encoding'=>'utf8'` option.
also added the `$this->charset('utf8')` to my view.

Now, when I use the `find('list')` and echo its content I get those known question-marks. But, when I use the `find('all)` method, the data is delivered correctly.

And my questions are:

1. Why?
2. Who is to blame?
3. How to solve ?(I really prefer the list way..)
4. Should I drink more coffee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try $this->find('all') and then use set to extract the values, like Set::extract('/Post/title', $posts); and print it out. if the find all was good and the set::extract is bad there could be a bug. If it works like normal then there is something weird as that is what the core does.

Comment: thanks @dogmatic69, but this is the problem. i mean: i figured it out because i bypassed it already with find-all. my need is for the list (I have many calls of that kind.. and it seems wrong to bypass a basic framework feature.), guess you have a point about the bug, i usually don't think that it's not my fault lol.

Comment: a bug on that part of the code is a long shot, but not impossible. try write some test cases for the problem and see what you come up with